# File Sharing with iTunes on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

"To enable File Sharing in your app, you simply set the boolean flag `UIFileSharingEnabled` in your `info.plist`."
That's the only tip I've found as answer to many questions about file sharing on iOS.

But this seems not to be enough!

I have "Application supports iTunes file sharing" (Boolean) set to `YES` in my `Info.plist`. And checked in source code the correct entry:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>
```

But iTunes does not show my apps in the list enabled for shared documents. Not on latest versions of iTunes/Mac nor iTunes/Windows. Not for Devices from iOS version 5 to 8.1.

I have deleted my apps on the devices, then re-installed from Xcode.
But I don't have registered any documents for "Open with...", because I don't need that.

What else is to do?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a test app without this problem I've compared the info.plist of the two apps. In the test app there was an key "Bundle name" with the value (String) "${PRODUCT_NAME}", in my other app not. After adding this key/value, file sharing is working now.